# @import in @media not working in Firefox 3.0.3

Tags: css, media, firefox-3

This is what I have, which works in IE7, but not in Firefox:

```
@media screen { @import 'screen.css'; }
```

It works outside of the @media block in Firefox:

```
@import 'screen.css';
```

**UPDATE:**

This works:

```
@media screen { 

    .yui-d3f
    {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        height: 250px;
    }

}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firefox is following the CSS2 specification, while IE is playing fast and loose, as it were.

The exact reason is that `@import` directives must be the first directives after the optional `@charset` directive.  They cannot appear inside of any block.  If you want an `@import` to apply to only one media type, specify that after the imported URI.

Here is the pertinent section of the CSS2 specification: [6.3 The `@import` rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#at-import).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so Firefox doesn't like the method I chose, favouring:

```
@import 'stylesheet.css' media_type;
```

But IE7 doesn't understand this method, but this could be good:

```
@import 'firefox-screen.css' screen;
@media screen { @import 'IE7-screen.css'; }
```