# How to import printing stylesheet using @media print query?

Tags: css, printing, import, media-queries

I want to move my printing stylesheet into a seperate file to be imported using @media query. I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work, at least on Chrome:

```
h1 {
....
}

....

@media screen {
....
}

@media print {
 @import "print.css";
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/224278/2151120

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@import` supports media types and media queries on its own, so you would pass the media query into the `@import` statement rather than nesting it in a `@media` rule:

```
@import "print.css" print;
```

Furthermore you cannot add an `@import` statement to style rules, so in this case you would need to put it all the way on top. If you cannot do so for cascading reasons, you cannot use `@import`; you need to include the print stylesheet using a `<link media="print">` element or similar instead.

Comment: Umm, but the rules would cascade the wrong way if I put it at the top.

Comment: Oh, yes, why I didn't think of using a separate link element. Thanks!